# format_string is not working SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[WagesToSales] as ([Measures].[Value - Fact Wages]/(([Measures].[Value]) - ([Measures].[Sales]))), FORMAT_STRING= '0.00'
SELECT [Measures].[WagesToSales] ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Dim Date].[Date Key].[Date Key].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Store Type].[Store Type].[Store Type].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( Filter( [Dim Location].[Location Name].[Location Name].ALLMEMBERS, Instr( [Dim Location].[Location Name].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ), 'BOSTON' )  > 0  ) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Store Type].[Store Type].&[Boston] } ) ON COLUMNS  FROM [People Dashboard 1]))
```

result still not displaying two decimals.

[image]

is there something that i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You Try:

change

```
FORMAT_STRING= '0.00'
```

to

```
FORMAT_STRING='##0.00'
```

Comment: You check here: 
http://blog.oraylis.de/2009/11/how-to-define-an-excel-compliant-format-strings-for-a-cube/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[WagesToSales] as 
  DIVIDE(
    [Measures].[Value - Fact Wages]
   ,[Measures].[Value] - [Measures].[Sales]
  )
 , FORMAT_STRING= "0.00"
SELECT 
  [Measures].[WagesToSales] ON 0
, NON EMPTY 
     [Dim Date].[Date Key].[Date Key].ALLMEMBERS 
   * [Dim Store Type].[Store Type].[Store Type].ALLMEMBERS 
   ON 1
FROM 
  ( 
   SELECT 
       Filter( 
         [Dim Location].[Location Name].[Location Name].ALLMEMBERS
     , Instr( 
         [Dim Location].[Location Name].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' )
      , 'BOSTON' 
       )  > 0  
       ) 
      ON 0
   FROM 
     ( 
       SELECT 
          [Dim Store Type].[Store Type].&[Boston] ON 0
       FROM [People Dashboard 1]
     )
);
```

Comment: i tried your code and the result is still the same with mine :(.